# How would i get the job id out of the list

Tags: c#

Hi how would i get the job id out of this class list object.

```
private List<Job> jobs = new List<Job>()
        {
            new Job(1000, "Junior Developer", "Junior development role, degree required but no experience.", "Manchester", 24000),
            new Job(1001, "Senior Developer", "Senior developer full-stack developer required, experience leading projects required.", "Manchester", 30000),
            new Job(1002, "Project Manager", "Experienced project manager required.", "Stockport", 40000),
            new Job(1003, "Software Tester", "Junior tester required to test mobile apps.", "Salford", 24000)
        };


    public Job GetById(int jobId)
    {
       // Returns the job with the given Id
     }

        }
```

Comment: Try a for loop over `jobs` list.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `FirstOrDefault()` to [search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netcore-3.1) for it.

```
public Job GetById(int jobId) => jobs.FirstOrDefault(job => job.Id == jobId);
```

Though, semantically `SingleOrDefault()` might be better choice given you are using an "ID" to search for items.

Comment: Thanks for you help 